# Share To Instagram stories never resolves promise

Tags: react-native

Could anyone with experience using https://github.com/react-native-share lib to share on Instagram stories help me? If i try to share an image,  it shares to Instagram with success, but promise  never resolves :(.  Run on iOS only.
Any thoughts, anyone, thank you :)

Code snippet i have:

```js
   (async () => {
      const options = {
        method: Share.InstagramStories.SHARE_BACKGROUND_IMAGE,
        social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM_STORIES,
        backgroundImage: uri,
      };

      try {
        const res =  await Share.shareSingle(options);

        console.log({res}, 'Never happen');
      } catch (err) {
        console.log({err}, 'Also never happen');
      }
   })()
```

Comment: did you try with a `.then`?

Comment: Yes i did, in fact i found out it is already asked here: https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/issues/808#issuecomment-658324174 , but no answer :(

Comment: Wrap your last two lines into try ... catch construct and see what it actually catches, looks like something is erring the promise

Comment: @crtag  thank you, I corrected example, but still no promise resolved in catch part.

Comment: Look at the implementation, it might help https://github.com/react-native-share/react-native-share/blob/25e48ff25141303b51ec616120d83c9280d0c64c/index.js#L287

Comment: @crtag, thank you for pointing me out to source code. It seems that the code always resolves promise (or rejects it), but on my side i do not see it. Anyway, i will keep solution i wrote down bellow.

Answer (score 1):

I could not solve to directly post to Instagram Stories, but open Instagram where user is presented inside the app to choose Feed or Story, which is fine for me.

```js
 (async () => {
    const options = {
      social: Share.Social.INSTAGRAM,
      url: imageBase64
    };

    const res = await Share.shareSingle(options);
    console.log({res})
})()
```